# How to integrate Django oAuth in flutter App

Tags: django, flutter, dart, oauth-2.0

We are currently working on an app that uses Django auth-users and oauth2 as authorization. Now I was looking at the documentation and examples of the flutter-package [oauth2](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2), and the tutorial looks quite easy. But it doesn't really work. Does anybody already have a simple solution for oauth2 with django that he could share, or maybe a link to a github project that could help me?